# Cannot convert return expression of type '()' to return type 'Double'

Tags: swift, function, return-type

what's a a expression of type '()' ?

and this version is not correct

```
var compteEnBanque: Double = 999.5


func shopping(_ new: Double) -> Double {
    guard compteEnBanque >= new else {
        return compteEnBanque
    }
    return compteEnBanque -= new
}
```

**error : Cannot convert return expression of type '()' to return type 'Double'**

but this version is correct

```
    var compteEnBanque: Double = 999.5


func shopping(_ new: Double) -> Double {
    guard compteEnBanque >= new else {
        return compteEnBanque
    }
    return compteEnBanque - new
}
```

Sorry, I'm not english native and thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`()` is an empty tuple in Swift - which is also `Void`.

The `-=` operator returns `Void`, since it mutates the left-hand side operand rather than returning its new value.

You should first do `-=` and then return the value of the left-hand side operand to both update it and then return its new value.

```
var compteEnBanque: Double = 999.5


func shopping(_ new: Double) -> Double {
    guard compteEnBanque >= new else {
        return compteEnBanque
    }
    compteEnBanque -= new
    return compteEnBanque
}
```

Comment: Thank you Dávid

"The -= operator returns Void, since it mutates the left-hand side operand rather than returning its new value."

 Both sides are var: Double, how do you account for the Bank mute to Void?

Sorry I'm a novice.

Comment: @Ryo both sides of the operator are "operands" - values that the operators operates on. The return value is a 3rd value, the result of applying the operator to the 2 operands. In case of `-=`, the return value is `Void`, since the result is actually assigned back to the left-hand side operand, rather than returned as a return value.

Comment: Thanks for your time @Dávid